# Add Speed to WASD Controls for A-Frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

How can I increase the speed of the WASD Controls for my WebVR page?
Because now it goes really slow.

```
<a-entity position="0 1.8 0" camera look-controls wasd-controls>
  <a-camera id="camera">
    <a-cursor color="#333" maxDistance="30"></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `wasd-controls` component has several options, described in the [A-Frame v0.4.0 docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/wasd-controls.html#properties). Increasing acceleration, or decreasing easing, will both make the camera move faster.

```
<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls="acceleration: 100">
  <!-- ... -->
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration config does not affect top speed. If you are looking to change top speed, [I made a fork of aframe](https://github.com/kkota1/wasd-world) that includes configs for speed as well as new features like gravity, look sensitivity, and Y-axis inversion.

Comment: your github is now 404 not found

Comment: @eviltik it's proprietary now, check https://3axis.io